# How to add style programmatically to Word document

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-word, ms-office, office-interop

I have a dynamically created textbox that opens in Word.
I am trying to give it one of the default styles in Word 2010 ("Colored Fill, White Outline - Accent 1)
however I have not been able to find the code to do this.

Below is what I have so far, which creates and offsets the textbox:

```
oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add
Dim titleBanner As Word.Shape
titleBanner = oDoc.Shapes.AddTextbox(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 81.0#, 20.5, 456.75, 24.75)
titleBanner.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "This is a textbox!"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at

http://docx.codeplex.com/

you won't need to use Com and it allows you to do formating as well

Comment: Thanks but I already have a 30 page document created using the above method. Only thing remaining is the styling the client requested.  I have already managed to use a table style in Excel and thought the same would be possible in Word.

Comment: In the end I chose to use the docx plug in as suggested above and use the "replace" function to preserve my large document and make it easy to host this on a server.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did:

1. Open Word
2. Start record a macro
3. Perform a find and replace from a color in my document to the color
   that I want
4. Stop recording the macro
5. Open the VBA macro
6. Find the integer value for the color
7. Replace -738148353 in the example statement below with your value:

   selection.Font.Color = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColor)(-738148353);